# ASP.Net Core. Detect if configured for https on startup?

Tags: asp.net-core, samesite

I have a .net ASP Core 2.1 app. The app can be setup via HTTP or HTTPs. In startup, I need to set the options.Cookie.SameSite to SameSite.None if we're running https, or -1 if running http.

Is there anyway to tell how the app is configured to run at startup. I was thinking I might just have to put a flag in the appsettings.json to flag this behavior but that's kind of lame.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                //if https I want below. If not I want it to be set to -1
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can judge whether it is `http` or `https` when appending cookies. Like the following.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext =>
                CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
        });
    }
private void CheckSameSite(HttpContext httpContext, CookieOptions options)
    {
        if (options.SameSite == SameSiteMode.None)
        {      
            if (!(httpContext.Request.IsHttps))
            {
                options.SameSite = (SameSiteMode)(-1);
            }
        }
    }
//....
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      //...
      app.UseCookiePolicy();
      //...
    }
```

Test result(remember clear the cookie first):
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. This is very clear. It will take me a little time to play with this, I'm a bit slow. I'll let you know.

Comment: If there are any updates, please let me know in time.

Comment: I was having a hard time integrating the fix into our framework. Nothing to do with your suggestion, just my slowness.  This seems to be exactly what I needed. Thankyou